# JavaScript code doesn't work inside foreach

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, web

im working in laravel framework now (newbie, just starting),
I have a foreach statement, that will show the information on a card using card style bootstrap,
i have a script code that supposedly run on each card. however, the script only works on the first card only, why this happend ?

this is my code

```
@foreach ($cutomers as $customer)
    <div class="column">
        <div class="card text-white bg-dark countdown">
           <h3 class="card-title" id="b">{{$customer->name</h3>
            <p class="card-text">{{$election->last_name}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{$election->age}}</p>
            <p id="demo"></p>
            <script>
               document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "test";
            </script>
       </div>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

the  part supposedly run each loop inside foreach

*sorry for my bad english

Comment: It's because you're using an ID as the identifier, which will only usually get the first reference of that element. You'll what to change the `<p>` element to something like `<p class="demo"></p>` and then access it via `document.getElementsByClassName("demo").....` - however there are *MUCH* more efficient ways of completing what you're trying to do here

Comment: You are generating an `id` attribute in a loop, so you are generating many `id`'s with the same `id`. They must be UNIQUE on a page for them to work

Comment: ahh i see, ive been struggling with this for several hours, thank you all haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the id `demo` multiple times. Use this instead:

```
@foreach ($cutomers as $key => $customer)
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card text-white bg-dark countdown">
                <h3 class="card-title" id="b">{{$customer->name}}</h3>
                <p class="card-text">{{$election->last_name}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{$election->age}}</p>
                <p id="demo_{{ $key }}"></p>
                <script>
                    document.getElementById("demo_{{ $key }}").innerHTML = "test_{{ $key }}";
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

---

Please remember that blade code is executed on server (**only** on server), and javascript code is executed on browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
@foreach ($cutomers as $key => $customer)
    <div class="column">
        <div class="card text-white bg-dark countdown">
            <h3 class="card-title" id="b">{{$customer->name}}</h3>
            <p class="card-text">{{$election->last_name}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{$election->age}}</p>
            <p id="demo[{{$key}}]"></p>
            <script>
                document.getElementById("("demo["{{$key}}"]")).innerHTML = "your_value";
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```